# How to Shuffle and Echo 3 Random Words out of a String?

Tags: php, string, random

a question about getting some random words out of a bigger string *after* it has been translated:

```
<?=__("water, chicken, banana, rice, bread, salt, cucumber, ananas, peach")?>
```

on my site currently outputs:

```
water, kip, banaan, rijst, zout, komkommer, ananas, perzik
```

now imagine I want to get just 3 words from that on random. How do I do that?

It's important not to touch the words parts inside `__("` & `")` part! The translater cannot process when `__($var)` but ONLY when `__("word1, word2, word3")`.

I imagine the best is to first put the the outcome into a string or array (this is how far I came please don't laugh)

```
$translated = __("water, chicken, banana, rice, bread, salt, cucumber");
echo $translated;
# shuffle & echo 3 items
```

How do I proceed from here to randomly get 3 words out of `$entireString` ?

## update

```
    $array = explode(',', $translated);
    $randomKeys = array_rand($array, 3);
    $translated = '';
    foreach(array_keys($randomKeys) as $key){
      $translated .= $array[$key].' ';  // use space or comma
    }

    echo $translated;
```

echos: `water kip banaan` always. so it does not seem to shuffle well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

```
$array = explode(',', $str);
$randomKeys = array_rand($array, 3);
$str = '';
foreach($randomKeys as $key){
  $str .= $array[$key].' ';  // use space or comma
}
```

Comment: `$randomString = implode(',' array_rand($array, 3));` this line has a error it seems or is dreamweaver a silly app?

Comment: @Sam : It was a mistake of `,` , I changed it.

Comment: and `2,1,8` when I refresh, so its doing the shuffle, but not echoing all the elements...  Would like to have something like "while i<5" echo the 5 elements and put "•"  in front and "<br/>" at the end of the element so to get a list

Comment: Thanks! there seems to be an error in the second line ( dreamweaver complaning again)

Comment: Thanks, it now returns `water kip banaan`  after refresh no matter what I do, ALWAYS the same, first three elements of the array (see updated question)

Answer (score 2):

```
function randomstr($str, $num = 3) {
   $str = explode(',', $str);
   return implode(',' array_rand($array, $num));
}
```

Now:

```
<?=__(randomstr("water, chicken, banana, rice, bread, salt, cucumber, ananas, peach"))?>
```

Or in `function __`:

```
function __($string) {
   $string = randomstr($string);
   // more your code
}
```

Comment: `__($...)` is not allowed as written in the question. Must be words inbetween sorry I wasn't clear (updated question)

Comment: @Sam did you tried second variant (`function __($string) {`)?

Comment: yep, that also doesnt work on my site. relly can only touch up the `@translatedString` only, not the __("..."); part.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to store the values not as string, but as an array? If you cant just explode them by `,` then get a random element from the array and translate that one.

For example:

```
$translated = __("water, soup, rice, peanutbutter");
$translatedWords = explode(',',$translated);
shuffle($translatedWords); //Randomize them
```

Would output something like `Soep, Rijst, Pindakaas, Water`

(Also __ is quite an odd name for a function)

Comment: Actually `__` is not a weird name. `_` is used by gettext, and since this function does a similar job (translating stuff), I'd say the name is adequate.

Comment: Indeed, and its very short = love it!

Comment: I like your solution +1, but the question was to get only ,say, 3 items not the entire string shuffled. How would you implement the selective grasp in your proposal?

Comment: `echo shuffle($translatedWords);` echoes 1, that means you are using arrays  right? so how to echo this array correctly?

Comment: You can view the contents of the entire array by using `var_dump`, you can just echo the first 3 elements of the array using a simple for loop.

@Artefact2: I believe __ doesnt really describe what the function does.